# Document List API to Drive SDK and Client Login

Tags: google-drive-api

We used to have an application connector implementing the Document List Service v3 to upload documents to users account. Now that the service will be discontinued starting as of next Monday and we need to migrate to the Drive API/SDK we have the problem to migrate our current login schema .. we are unable to use the OAuth 2 protocol and we need to authenticate users with their username/password credentials.

```
DocumentsService myService = new DocumentsService("xxx");
myService.setUserCredentials(username, password);
```

The reason is that our application scans and processes documents asynchronously from MFD devices (printers) and all processing/storage job is done in a different moment on processing servers, thus the limitation that the processing service cannot ask any consens to the user.

We do the same for other online cloud storage application (e.g. Dropbox) where they allow special 'OAuth 1' schema on request for such 'enterprise' situations.

How can we do this with the new Drive API/SDK? I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation rather than the service account, also looks like not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is request authentication from you user once.   The server gives you back a refresh token.   Your automated application can then use this refresh token to get a new access token.   You only need to ask the user one time for authentication.  Then everything can run automated.

A service account wont really work in this instance because its meant for use with an account that you the developer own not a users account

Comment: Yes I do understand because is written clearly at the API page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/: "This means that service calls to the API are no longer supported, and features implemented using this API will not function after April 20, 2015"... and which of course includes ClientLogin as well as you point. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Update sorry I think I misunderstood your question initially.

Comment: No problems at all, thanks. Was searching for a confirmation that we had no chance then switch to OAuth.

Comment: You can also implement 2legged oauth2 using user impersonation with service accounts. Requires a gapps admin to give permission once and then you can pretend to be any user without requiring individual user flows or saving refresh tokens. But you should have started this months ago not 4 days before api expires